# How can a PHP programmer go to robotics

Tags: robotics

I am a PHP programmer with basic knowledge of c/c++ and electronics. But i have keen interest in robotics and AI.

1. What are the basic things that i
   need to learn before switching to
   the robotics ?
2. What languages are
   used to write the code and how is
   that code transferred to the chips ?
3. What are the basic components that i
   need to know ?

I would like to learn about the both hardware components and the programming part. (Are these different streams?)

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you are wanting to do? Are you purely trying to stay in the coding world or are you wanting to learn about the hardware also?

Comment: I just edited the question.. are these different streams i mean can i learn about the hardware and not the software or vice-versa... what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) What are the basic things that i
>   need to learn before switching to the
>   robotics ?

Really, all you need to know is what your goals and interests are.  Often, you can't find this out until you try a few things. Without this knowledge, there's a huge amount to learn.  Motion, size, code volume, and interfaces are all very different in various systems.

> 2) What languages are used to write
>   the code and how is that code
>   transferred to the chips ?

The vast majority of the time, code is written in C, possibly with a little bit of assembler to do some hardware operations that can't be done in C.  Sometimes, C is used to build up an operating system, and then code is written for that operating system (again, still using C) or a virtual machine is created, which runs a higher-level language like Java, Lua, or C#.

Usually, this is done on a PC with a cross-compiler, which creates a hex or  which cannot run on the machine that the compiler runs on, but can run on the micro.  Then, a programmer is used to interface with the microcontroller using USB, serial, or even Ethernet.  Sometimes, this 'programmer' is located on the same PCB as the microcontroller, such as on the Arduino board.  Communication protocols like JTAG, ISP, and other various standard methods can be used, although some chips require specialized programmers.

> 3) What are the basic components that
>   i need to know ?

Again, this depends on what your end goal is.  You should have a basic understanding of electricity (Ohms' law can probably get you by in most cases, as well as an understanding of diodes and transistors/MOSFETs).   Blinking an LED is an easy first step (off a tall cliff).  If you're serious about robotics, you should learn about motor drivers, servos, and stepper motors.

> I would like to learn about the both
>   hardware components and the
>   programming part. Are these different
>   streams?

Only slightly so.  It is possible to use hardware components without having to write a program, and it is possible to buy premade hardware modules and then just do the programming part, but eventually the two go hand in hand.

Comment: Thanks this explains alot to me... I love robotics I really want o shift in this field, But I dont't understand how to start it.. you answer is very helpful to me.. Thanks very much.. do you think Python is helpful in this field ?

Comment: C is going to be, far and away, the **most** helpful language.  However, Python (Look at Cython and [python-on-a-chip](http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/)) might be usable.  Python's "batteries-included" approach won't fit on small micros, but it's a good language and could work on micros with larger memory space.  Start with C, and move to other languages as you gain experience.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.. I have some basic knowledge of c, but i never worked on the chip level, can u suggest some books or articles for startup

Comment: The best way of learning is probably by doing.  AVRFreaks has a lot of example code in C for the AVR processors, and most toolchains come with some example code for their targets. Other than that, datasheets are your new best friend.  Arduino has a C-like (really C++-like) language called Wiring which is a bit of a diversion, but can be helpful if you're not getting the concepts.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest starting with an Arduino board and one of the many "[Getting Started with Arduino](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596155514)"-style books out on the market. This is a very beginner-friendly way to get introduced to the world of embedded processors, device programming and simple circuit hacking. A few hours with an Arduino will also help you decide where your interests are really focused. (E.g. if you hate having to wire up an LED circuit just to see your program work, you probably want to focus on a more ready-made platform for robotics exploration. Whereas if you find the hardware tinkering appealing, you might want to move on to a very basic, bare-bones kit like the [Parallax Stingray](http://www.parallax.com/Store/Robots/AllRobots/tabid/128/ProductID/601/List/0/Default.aspx?SortField=ProductName,ProductName).)

Answer (score 2):

You should learn by experimentation.

To your questions:

1. You should learn basic electronics theory, and the basics of microcontrollers.
2. Code is often written in C, but sometimes it can be written in other languages like Basic, and some processors support .NET.
3. Resistors, capacitors, diodes and transistors are probably the most common devices you will encounter, in that order.

I would recommend you try with a board already available, like an Arduino or PICAXE.

Comment: All processors work with some form of assembly.  It's the availability of compilers that's the sticking point.  C++, Forth, Lua (eLua), and really all other languages are also possibilities, not just .NET and C#.  However, C and assembler are the two most common languages, because they get you 'close to the metal'.

Comment: Not necessarily true, but holds for most processors. For example, some processors natively execute languages far away from being assembly, like Java (they do execute bytecodes though, which is similar to assembly.)

Comment: If the processor executes java bytecode, then that is its assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in robotics for several years but before then I was in web, information retrieval field. So I can understand how the OP feels when s/he got interested in robotics but the skill set might seem very different. Indeed it is different but I just want to share a bit of my experience.

Basically the other people's responses are more direct and thorough answer.

If you're from web, not necessarily `php` programmer though, the necessity for web development is about to boom even in robotics. A few areas I can think of that are heavily dependent on web technologies:

- Needs for mobile devices as a human interface is getting bigger & bigger, where web or mobile phone apps do the work. `java script`, `android`, `iOS` are needed. An example of prominent projects might be the one called [`rosbridge`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge).
- Using web as a source of data is the same in robotics application development. Some people call it as `Cloud Robotics`.